# C++ Check if bit is equal to something

Tags: c++, if-statement, memory, char, bit

If I have a variable like this

```
int A = 0x00203450;
```

how would I check if the 3 value is set?
So I am checking if the 3 is right here

```
0x0020 -> 3 <- 450
```

I have tried this

```
if((A & 0x00003000) == 0x00003000)
{
    _sys_print("the 3 value is set")
}
```

And a few other things, none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you please give some examples for values where the test returns true and others where the test returns false? Actually I think that your `(A & ...)`-approach should work.

Comment: @StephanLechner `0xFFFF` return true but should be there are no `3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that a position in a hex-representation like a single `F` or your single `3` represents a nibble of 4 bits (or a "half byte" in your words). If I understand you right, then you want to check if the complete "nibble" is exactly `3`, i.e. `0011b`. Then the problem with expression `A & 0x00003000` is that it will "cut" away the first two bits of the nibble of interest, such that an input at this position could be `1111b`, or `1011b`, or `0111b`, or `0011b`, and `A & 000003000` would always give `0011` at this position.

So you should write `(A & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000)`, such that you actually test the complete nibble and not only the lowest two bits of it. See the following code that demonstrates this approach. Hope it helps.

```
int main() {

    int test[] = { 0x00203450, 0x00202450, 0x00207450, 0x0020F450, 0x00200450, 0 };

    for (int* t=test; *t; t++) {
        const char* result = ((*t & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000) ? "true" : "false";
        printf("%08X contains the 3: %s\n", *t, result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, this is all you need:

```
if((A & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000)
{
    _sys_print("the 3 value is set")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Based on a further clarification in a comment the answer appears to be:

```
(a & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000
```

That selects out the fourth least significant hex digit and checks if it is '3'.
So looking at that nibble alone in binary it will match '0011' but not match '0111'.

Here's a little test harness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isThree(int a){
    return (a & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000;
}

int check(int a,bool expect){
    if(isThree(a)==expect){
        return 0;
    }
    printf("ERROR: isThree(%x)!=%c\n",a,(expect?'T':'F'));
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int errors=0;
    errors+=check(0x00003000,true);
    errors+=check(0x00004000,false);
    errors+=check(0x0000F000,false);
    errors+=check(0x00000000,false);
    errors+=check(0xABCD3123,true);
    errors+=check(0xABCD7123,false);

    if(errors!=0){
        printf("ERRORS: %d\n",errors);
    }else{
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and it works fine for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int A = 0x00203450;

    if((A & 0x00003000) == 0x00003000)
        puts("3 is there");

    return 0;
}
```

prints that 3 is there. Are you sure about the _sys_print() function?

Edit: try

```
if((A & 0x0000F000) == 0x00003000)
```

This will get 0x0000< whatever A has here >000 and see if it's a 3.

Answer (score 0):

A integer `int` is a integer variable. When you initialize with `0x00203450`, the final representation will not be in this format but in binary `0b1000000011010001010000‬`. This why binary operator exist to manipulate bits of a variable.

That said, you want to know if there is a digit `3` in your number. For this you must manipulate your variable as hexadecimal:

You could do something like that:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int n = 0x00203450;
    if (n / 16 / 16 / 16 % 16 == 3) {
        std::cout << "There is a 3\n";
    }
}
```

A mush faster solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int n = 0x00203450;
    if ((n & 0xF000) == 0x3000) {
        std::cout << "There is a 3\n";
    }
}
```

The trick with binary operator only work for base number multiple of 2, like (4, 8 and 16).

Example for octal:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int n = 0342;
    if ((n & 0700) == 0300) {
        std::cout << "There is a 3\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify on "You can't manipulate a binary format and try to look for a hexadecimal digit without convert it into hexadecimal before"?

Comment: int is a integer you can not convert integer into binary or any other representation as integer is more abstract then representation itself. What you can do is working on a binary representation but you don't need to convert anything to do so.